# Error in R caret.train in method="gam"

Tags: r, regression

I am having an error whenever I try to use `gam` as a method in `caret.train` function.

`fit<- train(P~log(DR)+log(L2M)+s(TSM)+s(TH)+s(II),data=training,method="gam")`
`Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Here is one of the warnings:

```
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
model fit failed for Resample16: select=FALSE, method=GCV.Cp
```

Why is this happening? When I just use `gam` everything is fine, this only happens with `caret` package.

`dput(head(training))` output:

```
structure(list(TT = c(1.810376, 0.089206, 0.623906, 0.676775, 
0.206524, 1.014849), P = c(682L, 674L, 681L, 679L, 655L, 682L
), II = c(846000000L, 4790000L, 38600000L, 40600000L, 1379632L, 
7526080L), WSM = c(5272L, 144L, 576L, 576L, 2336L, 18696L), TSM = c(168704L, 
4608L, 18432L, 18432L, 74752L, 598272L), L2M = c(1.49e+09, 12600000, 
85700000, 1.24e+08, 4214560, 33560200), DR = c(2.52e+09, 18400000, 
1.3e+08, 1.8e+08, 5559030, 44681000), DW = c(11600000L, 5440000L, 
39600000L, 46400000L, 4920550L, 36812430L), TH = c(32.032843125, 
0.1880727305, 0.2003506939, 0.1983195715, 0.558498625, 0.495952125
)), .Names = c("TT", "P", "II", "WSM", "TSM", "L2M", "DR", "DW", 
"TH"), row.names = c(3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? For example, using `dput(training)` to show the `training` variable (or some subset of it on which the error still occurs? `dput(head(training))` would be a good start)?

Comment: I have updated the question with the results of `dput(head(training))`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, `caret` uses the new `mgcv` package for `gam` functions; I had attached the older implementation of "gam" - the `gam` library. When I detached the `gam` library and only used `mgcv.gam`, this issue was resolved.